# Perfomance center LrJson.dll is not loaded

Tags: loadrunner

I have two scripts in my own scenario in Performance Center.
One of the scripts sends messages to Artemis MQ, and another one - prepares disk volumes with different libraries.

If I run scripts in VU Generator - all scripts will pass. But if I run my scenario in Performance Center - I will catch errors:

- Extension lrwreplaymain.dll is not loaded. System error: [param not passed in call]
- Extension LrXml.dll is not loaded. System error: [param not passed in call]
- Extension LrJson.dll is not loaded. System error: [param not passed in call]

Did someone have the same problems? How did you solve it?

I have tried to change generators in the Performance Center scenario, also, I have written a new script, which sends messages to MQ. Nothing didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in VUGenerator script, that couldn't load some special libraries.

Comment: What was the problem, and what actions did you take to solve it? Please be specific.